# Autofill a field base on the dropdown menu

Tags: radix, basic

I'm creating a form and in it I have two fields.

One is a dropdown menu which contains all the cities zip code and another one where the city has to be written there. Both informations are from the same table and I would like to know if there is a way to autofill the city field based on the dropdown zip code selected ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Have an event that fires every time the value of your ZipCodeDropdown changes.
2. Query all the cities that has that zipcode.
3. Store the values in a dataTable.
4. Fill your CityCombobox by iterating through that dataTable.